# onbeforeunload, how to get redirect location?

Tags: javascript, browser

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {

}
```

How do I know what URL they're being redirected to? Or if they're just closing the window

Comment: I'd say you could analyze the element that generated the event and act in consecuence depending the type

Comment: How would one do that? I looked at the event argument that's passed in and didn't see anything interesting in it.

Comment: Are you trying to catch when an element is clicked, like an `<a>` tag, or are you trying to catch it when `location.href` is reassigned?

Comment: I'm trying to catch it in the `onbeforeunload` function, when `location.href` is reassignied (and also if an anchor tag is clicked).